# Creating an activity that overlays all other activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to figure out how to create an Activity that overlays all other Activities within my Android app.

What I mean by this is for the app to launch, then have the default launching activity show and then have a bar at the bottom of the screen that is always displayed, even if you call another activity to start the bar at the bottom of the screen will always be there?

Would anyone have an idea of how this would be achieved? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use a WindowManager to inflate a view overlay the other activities. The best way is to launch a service responsible for inflating the view and control it. Something like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view= (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);


WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
if (view.isShown()){
       wm.updateViewLayout(view, params);
}
else {

     // add view
     wm.addView(view, params);
}

view.setOnClickListeners(...);
...
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Where would I launch the service from? my main activity?

Comment: Yes, where you want inflate your view. Your main activity for example. When you want remove the view yo need call windowManager.remove(...).

Comment: So the view I inflate, does it have to be a child of my main layout that is inflated in my Main-activity, or can I inflate it from from a completely different layout?

Comment: It is completely independent of your layout

Comment: Can you give me an example of inflating a layout defined in the xml?

Comment: I have edited mi answer for show hoy you can inflate a view from  layout with windowManager.